Can SceneKit be used with Swift 6 Concurrency?
Note to the "golden hammer owner" that previously closed this question, claiming it is a duplicate of "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78921728/crash-when-preloading-sktextureatlas-in-swift-6"
My question is about SceneKit while the claimed duplicate is about SpriteKit.
My question is about delegate calls from SceneKit thread that cannot modify SCNNode, making them useless. The claimed duplicate is about using Sendable closures in SpriteKit. So not the same thing at all.
In no way does the answer to the claimed duplicate answers my question.
Please re-consider your opinion (and you can remove my disclaimer).

So, I did ask the question on Apple Forums, and because the question has been wrongly closed by a super-powered user that don't want to change its mind, here is the answer by Apple employee (extract: full link given below):

I encourage you to file a bug against SceneKit about it.
I think that you’re right: Sticking with the Swift 5 language mode is the correct option right now.

Full link: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/765543

I am trying to port SceneKit projects to Swift 6, and I just can't figure out how that's possible. I even start thinking SceneKit and Swift 6 concurrency just don't match together, and SceneKit projects should - hopefully for the time being only - stick to Swift 5.
The SCNSceneRendererDelegate methods are called in the SceneKit Thread.
If the delegate is a ViewController:
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    let aNode = SCNNode()

    func renderer(_ renderer: any SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        aNode.position.x = 10
    }
}

Then the compiler generates the error "Main actor-isolated instance method 'renderer(_:updateAtTime:)' cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement"
Which is fully understandable.
The compiler even tells you those methods can't be used for protocol conformance, unless:

Conformance is declare as @preconcurrency SCNSceneRendererDelegate like this:

class GameViewController: UIViewController, @preconcurrency SCNSceneRendererDelegate {

But that just delays the check to runtime, and therefore, crash in the SceneKit Thread happens at runtime...
Again, fully understandable.

or the delegate method is declared nonisolated like this:

    nonisolated func renderer(_ renderer: any SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        aNode.position.x = 10
    }

Which generates the compiler error: "Main actor-isolated property 'position' can not be mutated from a nonisolated context".
Again fully understandable.
If the delegate is not a ViewController but a nonisolated class, we also have the problem that SCNNode can't be used.
Nearly 100% of the SCNSceneRendererDelegate I've seen do use SCNNode or similar MainActor bound types, because they are meant for that.
So, where am I wrong ? What is the solution to use SceneKit SCNSceneRendererDelegate methods with full Swift 6 compilation ? Is that even possible for now ?
Edit: added code examples and rephrased the problem for better understanding (and re-opening).

Your question was not closed by a moderator. It was closed by two normal users, one of them has the so-called gold hammer which allows them to close a question as a duplicate unilaterally. As someone with nearly 3K reputation, you really should be aware of this difference. You can recognize moderators by the blue diamond next to their name. In any case, even if it isn't a duplicate, I think your question could really do with a [mre].

OK, so I modified the text to indicate it is not a moderator that  closed it, and also to provide minimal example. Still, it is obvious that the claimed duplication is wrong with the given SO thread, if only for the fact that they don't address the same libraries. It may well be a duplicate of some SO thread, but not this one. How can I call for a fair arbitration ?

It is currently in the reopen review queue, so it might reopened (or not, because if other people agree that it needs a [mre], then it will likely be kept closed). You can also ask a question on [meta], but that does invite extra scrutiny to your question. You can also try tagging @matt to reconsider.

@matt with the update of the question, can you please reconsider your closing this question as a duplicate of "Crash when preloading SKTextureAtlas in Swift 6" (you may consider it is a duplicate of another). In addition, I would emphasis, that this is in no way a criticism to Swift 6 concurrency, which I am in favor of. It is a factual statement that - if I am not mistaken - SceneKit and Swift 6 concurrency don't go along, and that SceneKit therefore needs upgrade.
